# python compare 2 lists of values to check that received is in the table

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 lists

```
  Received = [0xFF, 0xOF, 0xF, 0x00)], 
  HeartbeatReply list = ([[0xFF, 0xOF, 0xF, 0x00],
                          [0xB0, 0x40, 0xBF,0x4F],
                          [0xE9, 0x19, 0xE6,0x16]]),
```

I want to be able to check if `received[]` is in `HeartbeatReply list[]` 
I know how to check if a single value is in the list but check if all values are in the list in Python.. in the correct order.. I'm not sure..

Comment: `recieved in heartbeatreply` is very likely what you want

Answer (score 0):

(this is probably a duplicate but I couldn't find one quickly)

Believe it or not: there is a notation for that!

```
recieved = ['0xFF', '0xOF', '0xF', '0x00'] 
heartbeatReply = [['0xFF', '0xOF', '0xF', '0x00'], ['0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF','0x4F'], ['0xE9', '0x19', '0xE6','0x16']]

print(recieved in heartbeatReply)
```

all sequences in python support a `in` operator to check if something is a member of that list, it works the same way if that member is a list itself.